# Java: JList getSelectedValue() NPE

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I'm getting a NPE when trying to run my script and I don't understand why, the goal is to run the file selected in my JList, so here's the relevant bits of code, starting with my population of the JList:

```
File f1 = new File("ARForm.java");
String assetClasses = f1.getAbsolutePath();
String[] splits = assetClasses.split(":");
String pathName = splits[0] + ":\\";
File dir = new File(pathName);
String[] lista = dir.list();
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
JList list1 = new JList(lista);
JScrollPane js = new JScrollPane(list1);
```

And here is the part of the class listing the NPE, the marked line, these two groups of code are from two different classes.

```
Object fileName;
ARForm mform;

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
    try{
        **fileName = mform.list1.getSelectedValue();**
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(fileName.toString());
    }
}
```

If this isn't enough let me know and ill post the full classes.
And if there are easier ways to do what I've done let me know please.

**EDIT**

Here are my classes, I realize some of the imports are unnecessary, I got lazy with copy/paste:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class Autorun extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ARForm mform = new ARForm();
        mform.setTitle("Security Roulette");
        mform.pack();
        mform.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mform.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mform.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ARForm extends JFrame{
    JButton runButton;
    JLabel lab;
    File f1 = new File("ARForm.java");
    String assetClasses = f1.getAbsolutePath();
    String[] splits = assetClasses.split(":");
    String pathName = splits[0] + ":\\";
    File dir = new File(pathName);
    String[] lista = dir.list();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
    JList list1 = new JList(lista);
    JScrollPane js = new JScrollPane(list1);


    public ARForm(){
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        jp.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        jp.add(js);
        jp.add(runButton = new JButton("Run"));
        runButton.setBounds(186, 10, 89, 23);
        runButton.addActionListener(new ButtonAction());
        add(jp);
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ButtonAction implements ActionListener{
    Object fileName;
    ARForm mform;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
        try{
            fileName = mform.list1.getSelectedValue();
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(fileName.toString());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Yo Mama!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason you're getting a null pointer exception is because 1- `mform` is `null` or `mform.list1` is `null` or nothing is selected in the list when the `actionPerformed` is executed

Comment: The top lines of the stack trace would be useful for us to help you.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ButtonAction.actionPerformed(ButtonAction.java:12)

Comment: How can they be null? I've initialized mform, mform.list1 works i know because the list/scrollpane is populated on the GUI when run, and I know I selected something before clicking the button. Is there a way to follow the full path of the program to figure out where its breaking down?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized `ARForm mform`. Perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: It gets initialized in a different class, with the static main method, the ARForm mform is only there to pull the JList from, sorry if this isnt really an answer, I'm bad with the vocab like initialize...